# Select MKPolygon on tap

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am trying to allow users to select polygons on a map using xamarin forms iOS and apply a stroke to the ones they have selected. I cannot figure out how to create a tap gesture in c# this way.

I am creating the polygons via

```
var blockOverlay = MKPolygon.FromCoordinates(coords);
 Constants.nativeMap.AddOverlay(blockOverlay);
```

Ideally I would like it to look like my
[Android Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFxrJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your `MKMapView` and convert the captured tap coordinates to a map point and test if it exists within any of your overlays.

#### Example:

```
var uiTapGesture = new UITapGestureRecognizer(tappedGesture =>
{
    foreach (MKPolygon polygon in (tappedGesture.View as MKMapView).Overlays)
    {
        using (var render = new MKPolygonRenderer(polygon))
        {
            var coord2D = nativeMap.ConvertPoint(tappedGesture.LocationInView(nativeMap), nativeMap);
            var mapPoint = MKMapPoint.FromCoordinate(coord2D);
            var polyTouched = render.Path.ContainsPoint(render.PointForMapPoint(mapPoint), true);
            if (polyTouched)
                Console.WriteLine($"tapped: {polygon}");
        }
    }
});
nativeMap.AddGestureRecognizer(uiTapGesture);
```

Note: This is assuming you are using `MKPolygon` for your overlays, if not, adjust accordingly.

Comment: Works perfect thanks, only thing I changed was I added the renders into a dictionary and iterated through that so I was able to change the color/stroke when clicked.